# How to run c project in console

Tags: c, console, project

Hello I have a project written in C that contains four .c files in different directories.These are `ipv4_lib.c` `udp_lib.c` `projekt_C.c` `programLib.c`

I 've written it in eclipse and everything works fine and it's easy to run,but now I have to run it in console.I have already run programs in console,but they were much easier and usually contained one or two headers in the same directory,so all I had to do was compile each files and run the main one.

But I have no idea how to run project.Is there some command to do that or something like that? Thanks

Comment: When you say "run", do you really mean *build*? Do the project have a `Makefile` that you can use to build?

Comment: In order to run a program, you must first compile all of the source files, and then link those (as well as the runtime libraries) into an executable, which you can then run. Have you done all of that?

Answer (score 1):

Look into GCC and Clang:

- GCC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection
- Clang: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang, https://clang.llvm.org/

Both are compilers you can use to compile your source code via the terminal. GCC is has been around longer and has better support but can be a little slow. Clang is newer, so less widely used, but is noticeably faster than GCC at compiling source code.

An example Clang command in your terminal:
`clang -o hello hello.c && ./hello`

This will compile your `hello.c` file and give you a `hello` executable that you can then run. We'll just assume that running the `hello` program prints `Hello, World!` to the console.